# Series converge/disconverge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove/disprove this:

$1.$ If $\sum a_n$ converge then $\sum a_n*a_{n+1} $ converge.

$2.$ if $\sum a_n$ converge then $\sum \frac{a_n*\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}$ converge.

Someone can give me a hint which test should I use or which series to compare,
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) take

$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\implies a_n{a_{n+1}}=-\frac1{\sqrt n\;\sqrt{n+1}}$$

For (2) use [Abel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) (why can you?) .

Comment: Thanks!!! I can use Abel's Test because sqrt(n)/(sqrt(n)+1) is monotonic and bounded?

Comment: @Tim Indeed so. Nice!